# SSL Retrofit Android : Stream does not represent a pkcs12 key store

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate, retrofit2, android-keystore

I am unable to load keystore.

- I want to add sslSocketFactory in OkHttpClient Retrofit
- After Loading ".p12" File from inputstream into keystore.load method i am getting below exception

"Method threw 'java.io.IOException' exception. stream does not represent a pkcs12 key store retrofit android".

### Method which returns SSLSocketFactory

```
public static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {

    SSLContext sslContext = null;

    try {

        String password = ""; // .p12 is without a password.

        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        InputStream caInput = MainApplication.context.getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.raw.generic_client_cert); // file present in Row directory with "generic_client_cert.p12" name.

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
```

---

```
        keyStore.load(caInput, password.toCharArray());
```

### Exception at above line.

```
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");

        kmf.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());

        KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();


        // creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();

}
```

What went wrong? any help will be great (^_^)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `.cer` file instead?

Comment: Client authentication requirement is generic-client-cert.p12, so i dont have any choice.

Comment: Try the following `keyStore.load(caInput, password.toCharArray());
// creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in the KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tm, null);`

Comment: More info at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html